# How to answer questions about the status of divine weapons?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

How do we answer questions such as:

- [What happened to the Vijaya bow after Karna's death?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/13872)
- [What did the Pandavas do with the oldest sword in the world?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3236)
- [What happened to the Akshaya Patra after the exile?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2247)

I can think of more questions like this:

- Where is Arjuna's Gāṇḍīva right now? Where is Bhīma's gada?
- What did Rāma do with his Kodaṇḍa bow before giving up his life? Where is it right now?
- What did Janaka do with the broken Pināka?
- Who has Viṣṇu's Śarṅga bow right now?
- Who took Rāvaṇa's Chandrahāsa sword after he was killed in battle?
- Rāvaṇa threw a divine javelin (śakti) on Lakṣmaṇa after which Lakṣmaṇa fell unconscious. Did anyone collect that spear? Where is that spear now?

No reason to worry though, I'm not planning to ask the above :)

But how should one answer such questions? Should we encourage or discourage users from asking such questions given that there are hundreds of these weapons in Hindu mythology?

Comment: Most of the Astras are invoked using Mantra. Once mantra lost, Astras are lost. So, answer for most of these questions is same.

Comment: Bhima's Gada and Ravana's spear wouldn't be good questions to ask, since those aren't famous weapons with illustrious origin stories.  But I think it's fine to ask what happened to famous weapons, since that's a topic often addressed in Hindu scripture.  (For instance the Sharnga bow flew out of Dwaraka and went back to Vishnu.)

Comment: @TheDestroyer I'm asking about śastras (not astras) where no invocation is necessary.

Comment: I think we should retain these Q's for they can make interesting reading. How to answer- with truth as stated by scripture. Typically, puranas and samhita granthas would carry info such as that being sought.